# sql except operation not working

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

```
$query = "SELECT _id , carModel, carBranchId, kilometers FROM `cars`
          EXCEP
          (SELECT c._id AS _id , c.carModel AS carModel, c.carBranchId AS carBranchId, c.kilometers AS kilometers FROM `cars` c INNER JOIN
          `orders` o ON c._id=o.carId and o.open='1')";
```

the excep dont work, each select give the right answer but they dont intersect

Comment: EXCEP? Really?? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-except-and-intersect-transact-sql

Comment: You have a typo - should be `EXCEPT`

Comment: fixed the typo still not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although you can use `EXCEPT`, I find this much more naturally written in other ways:

```
SELECT c._id, c.carModel, c.carBranchId, c.kilometers
FROM `cars` c LEFT JOIN
     `orders` o 
     ON c._id = o.carId and o.open = '1'
WHERE o.carID IS NULL;
```

Note:  The default column alias *is* the column name, so there is no need to repeat the alias.

or:

```
select c.*
from cars c
where not exists (select 1 from orders 0 where c._id = o.carId and o.open = '1');
```

Comment: it seems to work but can you explain somthing. the where o.carId IS NULL refers to table after the left join, so left join put null at all the row that dont have match?

Comment: @מיכאלביתן . . . Yes, that is how `left join`s work to find something in the first table that is not in the second.  I prefer `not exists` because I think the intention is clearer.